# Logging In as Another User in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have functionality like "Loging in as another user".
I tried method "switchIdentity" but is not my solution because change role too.For me need change only "ID".

How realize login in as another user in yii2?

Comment: It's not possible with yii way and even more, it's very bad idea. Identity should be switched for this feature.

Comment: We have administrator and operator role. When need change anything for us need do this from administrator role.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442609/how-to-change-current-user-in-yii2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change current user in Yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442609/how-to-change-current-user-in-yii2)